# Pattern Matching and List Comprehension in List of Tuples

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

```
type a = [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]

fun:: a -> Int
func [a,b,c,d] = ?
```

I have a list of tuples like this  what i required is to apply `list comprehensions` or `pattern matching` .. example taking *sum or filter only  divide 2 numbers* ... i just want a start how to access values and or a list comprehension to this  **List of Tuples**

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Simple example taking sum of the `a`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To sum up the `a`s, use something like this:

```
type A = [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]

func :: A -> Int
func tuples = sum [a | (a, b, c, d) <- tuples]
```

Also note that a type alias must begin with an upper case letter. Lower case letters are used for type *variables*.

Comment: thanks how to do this ? -->  `[x|x<-xs|x 'mod'2]`   .. is it possible ?

Comment: @Sudantha: To add a condition, separate it from the "generator" `x <- xs` with a comma, e.g. ```[x | x <- xs, x `mod` 2 == 0]```

Comment: thanks what i didnt got is how to apply it to the `A` ? as the above ur answer :-)

Comment: @Sudantha: Do you mean sum up only the even `a`s? ```sum [a | (a, b, c, d) <- tuples, a `mod` 2 == 0]```.

Comment: sorry confused ,, its the return data type .. thanks a lot u solved a bit prob :)

Comment: hey i just want to `func tuples =  [a | a <- tuples,a `mod` 2 == 0]` to this  to return all the mod2 ppl from the list of tuple but getting a error no idea `Instance of Integral (Int,Int,Int,Int) required for definition of func
`

Comment: i just required to print the evens of the list of tuple.

Comment: @Sudantha: `a <- tuples` will match `a` against _the entire tuple_. If you only want the first element you need to use `(a,b,c,d)` or `(a,_,_,_)`.

Answer (score 3):

hammar's answer covered list comprehensions, the basic schema for recursive functions using pattern matching is:

```
f [] = ..
f ((a,b,c,d):xs) = ..
```

So you need to specify a base case for a list containing no 4-tuples, and a recursive case for when the list consists of a 4-tuple `(a,b,c,d)` followed by a (possibly empty, possibly non-empty) list of 4-tuples `xs`. The pattern on the second line is a *nested pattern*: it first matches the list against a pattern like `(x:xs)`, i.e. element `x` followed by rest of list `xs`; and then it matches `x` against the 4-tuple structure.

Below, I'll give some basic examples. Note that you can also write this with standard higher-order functions, such as `filter` and `map`, and I'm deliberaty not mentioning things like `@`-patterns and strictness. I do not recommend doing it like this, but it's just to give you an idea!

When you want to sum the first part of the tuples, you could do it like this:

```
sum4 :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> Int
sum4 [] = 0
sum4 ((a,b,c,d):xs) = a + sum4 xs
```

If you want to filter out the tuples where all of `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are even:

```
filter4allEven :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]
filter4allEven [] = []
filter4allEven ((a,b,c,d):xs) 
    | all even [a,b,c,d] = (a,b,c,d) : filter4AllEven xs
    | otherwise = filter4AllEven xs
```

(If the use of `all` confuses you, just read `even a && even b && even c && even d`)

And finally, here's a function that returns all the even tuple components (tuples themselves can't be even!) in the same order as they appear in the argument list:

```
evenTupleComponents :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> [Int]
evenTupleComponents [] = []
evenTupleComponents ((a,b,c,d):xs) = [x | x <- [a,b,c,d], even x] ++ evenTupleComponents
```

Once you do a couple of exercises like these, you'll see why using standard functions is a good idea, since they all follow similar patterns, like applying a function to each tuple separately, including or excluding a tuple when it has some property or, more generally, giving a base value for the empty list and a combining function for the recursive case. For instance, I would write `evenTupleComponents` as `evenTupleComponents = filter even . concatMap (\(a,b,c,d) -> [a,b,c,d])`, but that's a different story :)